# How to return only a single regex match group in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a regex that has multiple match groups.

How in snowflake do I specify which match group to return?

I'm using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` but happy to use alternatives if they work better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR: Can't do *exactly* that, but you can the `'e'` option and use non-capturing groups with `(?:re)`.**

So to clarify, it seems Neil is asking for something that would return `word` for

```
select regexp_substr('bird is the word','(bird) (is) (the) (word)',1,4)
```

Unfortunately, I don't think Snowflake supports ***exactly*** this functionality today. There is an `'e'` (extract) parameter to REGEXP_SUBSTR, which allows you to extract a group only, but it always extracts the ***first*** group. The reason for that is that the `occurrence` parameter today means *occurrence of the entire regexp in the string*. Example

```
select regexp_substr('bird is cows are','([a-z]*) (is|are)',1,2,'e');
=> cows
```

You can achieve what you want by not using grouping for the groups before what you want, e.g.

```
select regexp_substr('bird is the word','bird (is) (the) (word)',1,1,'e');
-> is
select regexp_substr('bird is the word','bird is the (word)',1,1,'e');
-> word
```

However, that doesn't work if you want to use grouping for expressing alternatives, e.g.

```
select regexp_substr('cow is the word','(bird|cow) is the (word)',1,1,'e');
-> cow
```

Still, I see there would be value in providing an option to extract a particular group number, will raise it with Snowflake development :)

Comment: snowflake doesn't support non-capturing groups. It would be nice if it did though.

Comment: I get a syntax error when using a non-capturing group `Invalid regular expression: '(?:is) (the)', no argument for repetition operator: ?`

Comment: `regexp_substr` now supports the parameter `group_num` which allows you to specify the regex group to extract https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr#syntax

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has a `regexp_substr_all` function...

```
select regexp_substr_all('bird is the word','(bird) (is) (the) (word)',1,1,'c',4)[0];
```