# Snowflake regex

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Perhaps I have a field with html text and I want to extract only the first list. How can I do that?

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Hi guys</li>
  <li>Hi ladies</li>
</ul>
...
...
...
<ul>
  <li>I love dogs</li>
  <li>I love cats</li>
</ul>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
<ul>
  <li>Hi guys</li>
  <li>Hi ladies</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to implement **regexp_substr(HTML_TEXT, '< ul >(.*)< /ul >')**,
but then the output contains both lists.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return only a single regex match group in snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259349/how-to-return-only-a-single-regex-match-group-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Snowflake, why don't you use split function?

```
select '<ul>' || split( split( HTML_TEXT,'<ul>')[1] , '</ul>')[0] || '</ul>' from values
('some html codes that we want to skip
  <ul>
      <li>Hi guys</li>
      <li>Hi ladies</li>
    </ul>
    we dont want this either
    <ul>
      <li>I love dogs</li>
      <li>I love cats</li>
    </ul>') tmp(HTML_TEXT);
```

This will return:

```
<ul> <li>Hi guys</li> <li>Hi ladies</li> </ul>
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split.html

Answer (score 0):

I think an xml parsing option is probably a less fragile solution, but if you want to just get your regex working, I believe all you need is a "non-greedy" match which is denoted with a `?`

```sql
regexp_substr(HTML_TEXT, '< ul >(.*?)< /ul >')
```